# Finding a cluster of size $k$ with minimum intra-distance

Tags: algorithms, discrete-optimization, clustering

I've been looking for an algorithm for the following problem: given a set of $N$ points $x_1, \ldots, x_N$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and an integer $k \leq N$, find a set of $k$ points that minimizes its intra-distance, i.e., a set $S \subseteq [N]$ of size $k$ such that $\sum_{i, j \in S} d(x_i,x_j) $ is minimal among all sets of this size.

This looks closely related to clustering, with the difference that the goal is to obtain a *single* tightly-packed subset of points rather than a partition of the entire set of points. However, I wasn't able to find any algorithms well-suited for this task; all the variants I managed to find either try to find a partition with prescribed sizes (such as [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.188.1315&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) or try to find a single subset, but with unconstrained size.

While iterating over all $k$-subsets yields an $O(N^k)$ time algorithm, I imagine there is a more efficient way to go about this (algorithms without proven runtime bounds would be fine, too). Is a solution to this problem known?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to minimize $\sum_{i\in S} x_i$?  I would have expected something more like $\sum_{i\in S, j \in S: i < j} d(x_i,x_j)$, where $d()$ is Euclidean distance.

Comment: That's right, thanks! I just edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $y_i$ indicate whether $i \in S$.  The problem is to minimize $$\sum_{i<j} d(x_i,x_j) y_i y_j \tag1$$ subject to
$$\sum_i y_i = k \tag2$$
You can linearize the objective $(1)$ by introducing binary (or just nonnegative) variables $z_{i,j}$ and minimizing $$\sum_{i<j} d(x_i,x_j) z_{i,j}$$ subject to $(2)$ and
$$z_{i,j} \ge y_i + y_j - 1 \quad\text{for all $i<j$} \tag3$$
Constraint $(3)$ enforces the logical implication $y_i \land y_j \implies z_{i,j}$.

Comment: I see, thanks. Though that may not be faster than the trivial $O(N^k)$ time algorithm that enumerates over all subsets, right? Or is this in a class of efficiently solvable ILPs?

Comment: Even if not better in terms of computational complexity, in practice this should perform much better than brute-force enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

Another strategy that is asymptotically $O(N^k)$ but will probably perform much faster in practice is $A^*$ search. One admissible heuristic is the number of points left to add times the cost of adding the greedily least expensive point. Even tighter heuristics probably also exist.